# Values GridView in cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, mono

I am trying to get values of string that I keep inside GridView.
When I use regular BoundFields, things work get. I get whatever is needed with:

```
string my_value = myGrid.Rows [rowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
```

However, one grid needs to have hyperlinked entries in one of the columns. I did:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="domainName"
  HeaderText="Domain"
  SortExpression="domainName"
  HtmlEncode="false"
  DataFormatString="<a href=DomainConfiguration.aspx?suffix={0}>{0}</a>"
```

My ASPX page shows the correctly formed hyperlinks. However, if I retrieve Text for the cell, it returns "<\a href=DomainConfiguration.aspx?suffix=example.com>example.com</a>" [without the two extra slashes], instead of "example.com"

What do I need to do to get GridView working the way I want? [Yes, I would rather use GridView and not another control.]

Thank you.

Comment: Why you don't use `asp:HyperLinkField` instead of `asp:BoundField` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `asp:BoundField` to show hype link it is better use `asp:HyperLinkField` like:

```
 <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="domainName" HeaderText="domainName" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="DomainConfiguration.aspx?suffix={0}" DataTextField="domainName" />
    </Columns>
```

and to get string value of that column you should try this:

```
 string my_value= ((HyperLink)myGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead your `asp:Bounfield` use

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:HyperLink ID="editLink" runat="server"  onclick='<%#Eval("EditLink") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```